# Google Индексация

Tags: seo, индексация, google-search

Сделали все настройки для Seo google, но никак не получается изменить описание сайта, когда в поиске вводим через site:домейн сайта вводится правильное описание, но когда просто пишем домейн сайта (без site:), в чем проблема? Что не так сделали, или может еще нужно подождать? (запрос отправили и подождали дней 10 ничего не получилось, повторно отправили запрос и ждём уже где-то 2-3 дня).

Есть какие-то идеи или кто еще сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: *когда прости пишем домейн сайта(без site:)* - прощаем :)

Comment: для таких вопросов в сети stackexchange есть другие сайты, например http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ Попробуйте задать Ваш вопрос там.

Comment: @Alex Спасибо, попробую там написать :D

Comment: если вдруг не знаете, Вы можете использовать один аккаунт в сети [se], для этого на другом сайте нажмите [join this community](http://image.prntscr.com/image/01f4588fb7514bb186fb1815126db0b1.png) и потом на кнопку [confirm and create this accoun](http://image.prntscr.com/image/90048c1fe22b42689d491c3a428f3bcf.png)

Answer (score 0):

Надо подождать, когда все смениться. Это может занять время от 1 дня до 1 месяца.